# How to test a function in Angular Jasmine?

Tags: jasmine

I have a function in my service as:

```js
logError(message: string, stack: string) {
    console.log('LoggingService: ' + message);
}
```

and I want to test this function test case I am writing are as:

```js
it('should be created', inject([LoggerService], (loggerService: LoggerService) => {
    expect(loggerService).toBeTruthy();
  }));

it('log error should be called', inject([LoggerService], (loggerService: LoggerService) => {
    spyOn(loggerService, 'logError');
    expect(loggerService.logError).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(loggerService.logError).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
}));
```

Problem is when I run tests and I see code coverage it shows that **logError function is not covered** and also the console.log statement is not covered.

But when I change my approach from **spyOn to call the actual method** it says there are no expectations and I am not sure what will be the right expectaion in this case?

Any help on recommended approach is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`spyOn` installs a `spy` onto a method of an existing object but it doesn't invoke that method. Therefore, after installing the spy on a method, you need to call the method under test, which is supposed to invoke the spied/mocked method.

```
it('log error should be called', inject([LoggerService], (loggerService: LoggerService) => {
    spyOn(console, 'log');

    const error = 'abc';
    loggerService.logError(...);

    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(console.log)toHaveBeenCalledWith(error);
}));
```